# show rating average from database with jquery rating plugin

Tags: jquery, rating

So I was able to make it work, nothing difficult however I have a small problem. if the tutorial/article has a rating of 5 then 5 stars will be yellow, same if it is a rating of 4 or 3. But when the rating is 0 it will still make the first star yellow instead of making them all grey.

I'm using the plugin found on http://zensoftware.org/archives/483

and here is a link to a text file containing the code -> http://cmstutorials.org/code.txt

I don't think it's because of the plugin because when I remove the attribute **selected="selected"** all the stars become grey. so I guess it's something with my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be the [ceil](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) function.  If the rating is greater than zero but less than one, ceiling will return one, the smallest integer greater than the input.  For a rating system I would expect that you would really want to use [floor](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php) -- the largest integer not greater than the input.  That way to get a rating of 5, you'd have to get all 5's.

Having said that, if this is still happening with no ratings whatsoever then what I've said above is moot.

Comment: Is the entire block you are showing inside another loop? If so, that would make sense since ids need to be unique.